# Google Chrome Extension Permissions Issue, With Google Docs (Only)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-slides

I have a very simple Chrome Extension.  It's basically just:

**background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'alert("hi")' });
});
```

**manifest.json (the relevant parts):**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ABC",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "abc",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Start"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

The weird thing is that I can use it on most sites and it works perfectly fine: I get the `alert` as expected, with no errors.  However, if I try to use my extension on Google Slides I get:

> _generated_background_page.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_utjr0oy3rpsFq_R2YxAi2qNUIGItpj7ePhBCgqkdRY/edit#slide=id.g36de8e2a97_0_0". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
>       at chrome-extension://ijlnhinabondoaapkefkfbkickaemgdl/background.js:55:15

(Line 55 is the line `chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: 'alert("hi")' });`)

But since my manifest clearly gives me permission to that host (via the         `"*://*/*"` permissions entry) I have no idea what is causing this error or how to fix it.

Comment: I unfortunately can't repro your issue with that code on my own Slides presentation (the alert runs fine), but it might be worth trying `<all_urls>` rather than `*://*/*` as shown [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: I think this happens when the person/program accessing this file doesn't have permission. Can you try making your file public - available to all, and see if you still get this error?

Comment: @jgaul It's interesting that you can't repro; I've tried reducing my app down to just those two files (and the icons and readme) and still no luck.  I'll try remaking things, but it's just so odd: both when I use `<all_urls>` and when I follow @noogui's suggestion and share the presentation publically I still get the same error on any Google Docs (not just Slides) page.  However, the alert works fine on other sites /boggle

Comment: Ok, it's definitely not my code.  I tried installing the "Page Redder" example extension (from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) and it too gets `Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.` when I try to run in on Google Docs pages.

Comment: P.S. I thought maybe one of my other extensions (eg. the official Google Slides extension) could be causing problems, so I disabled every extension ... which didn't help.  I'm really at a loss as to how you are able to make things work @jgaul.

Comment: Sounds way frustrating :/ If you create a fresh Chrome profile (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824), load the unpacked extension into that profile, and then try to repro, do you still get that issue? Also, is the behavior the same across multiple Slides presentations?

Comment: @jgaul The behavior is the same across multiple Slides presentations, BUT when I tested in a fresh profile everything worked fine!  So I don't know what I could have in my "profile" that could be causing this (as I said I disabled all other extensions) but clearly something is broken.  I'll comment back here if I ever figure out what, but in the meantime if you want to summarize what you put in comments into an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Glad you're unblocked! Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unfortunately can't reproduce your issue with that code on my own Slides presentation (the alert runs fine).

Per the comments, I understand  neither of these helped:

1. Trying `<all_urls>` rather than `*://*/*` as shown [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).
2. Disabling all other Chrome extensions.

Given that, try this: Create a fresh [Chrome profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824), load the unpacked extension into that profile, and see if you can reproduce the issue.

If we can't reason with the gremlins, perhaps we can at least contain them.

Comment: Now if I could only figure out how to fix my original profile ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812500/google-chrome-extension-permissions-issue-with-google-docs-only